# What is the best way to setup Right to Left language locale in Craft?

Tags: localization, craft-features

I have been working on setting up locales for left-to-right languages. I wanted to know the support Craft provides for Right-to-Left languages like Arabic, Hebrew etc. Is there a plugin that could help or is it just the way other locales are setup (but with additional step)?

Any insight on this topic is helpful!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the locale as per below examples in your _layout.twig file.

```
<body class="{% if craft.locale == 'ar' %}rtl{% endif %}">
```

Your css would then be:

```
.rtl {direction:rtl}
```

And in your `<html>` like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="{% if craft.locale == 'ar' %}rtl{% endif %} lang="
{{craft.locale}}">
<head>
```

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to copy the format of a rtl language locale file in `craft > app > framework > i18n > data`. For instance if you select the Arabic `ar.php` file around line 268 set your language orientation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what support you're looking for, but the Craft Control Panel does fully support RTL languages like Arabic and Hebrew.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not talking about the Control Panel in craft. I want to add a new locales language (Hebrew or Arabic) and have it rendered from right to left. All the other languages that I have setup are left to right. When I tries Hebrew, it would render from left to right and not right to left. Is there a setting that I have to change while setting up that locale?